# Storing hexidecimal values

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'd like to store this value efficiently in MSSQL 2016:

```
6d017ed2a48846f0ac025dd8603902c7
```

i.e, Fixed-length, ranging from 0 to f, hexidecimal, right?.
Char(32) seems too expensive.

Any kind of help would be appreciated.  Thank you!

Comment: Why do you want to store this as a *string* in the first place?

Comment: I am hoping for a binary base 16 datatype, but didn't see any in the list of datatypes.  Hoping not to use a string.  This value is system-generated by another service.

Comment: What are you going to use these values as? Are you going to sort them or use them in a where clause (`where x > 6d017ed2a48846f0ac025dd8603902c7`)?

Comment: Only going to SELECT and GROUP them to count the times they appear in the table.  No comparisons like >, <.

Comment: Thought there'd be a better datatype.  Thanks for your input.  I'll leave this open for a day and see if any other answers appear.  Happy to mark your comment as the answer if that's the case.  Thank you.

Comment: Any benefit though depend on the use case - API hashes are sent as strings, git hashes are shown to humans. My gut instinct would be to use `binary(16)` but I'd still try to see how the data is used

Comment: @BrentShaub I got confused in my last comment. a single hexa digit is 4 bits meaning each binary byte can store two hexa digits. For some reason I thought it was the other way around. As soon as I've realized my mistake I've deleted that comment to not confuse other people as well.

Comment: Okay, here's what I'll do: I'll create two fields, one char(32) and the other binary(16).  After adding some data, I'll run some SELECTs with GROUP BYs and see how they play.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Ah!  Thanks for that.  Wondering if my eyes were playing tricks on me.  Thanks for scrubbing any false/misleading info away.

Comment: @BrentShaub there *is* a better type, `binary(16)`. If the value comes as a *string* from another system though, you may not *want* to change the data to something else. 8 extra bytes per row is insignificant unless you have millions of rows.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos After inserting both kinds and considering the volume of requests my new site will encounter, I'm wasting 16 bytes and using a char(32).  I can't read the binary(16) back again, only the first 16 characters, and that's not enough to know which video.  I could make another table of just these keys and an integer, and store the integer instead of this string, but that's more work than I'm hoping to do for this proof-of-concept.  I'm also using NodeJS to communicate with the database and trying to minimize code.  Thank you for your answers.

Comment: @BrentShaub what do you mean you can't read the `binary(16)` `, only the first 16 characters`? A `binary(16)` is just 16 bytes long. It's not a *string*, it's a binary value just like int or double or `numeric()`. They aren't treated as strings unless the query forces them to be converted to strings, eg because it uses string concatenation, or compares the field with a string literal instead of a strongly-typed parameter. In the query results you'll get back a byte buffer,not a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In almost all cases you shouldn't store this as a string at all. SQL Server has [`binary` and `varbinary` types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/binary-and-varbinary-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

This string represents a 16-byte binary value. If the expected size is fixed, it can be stored as a `binary(16)`. If the size changes, it can be stored as a `varbinary(N)` where `N` is the maximum expected size.

*Don't* use `varbinary(max)`, that's meant to store BLOBs and has special storage and indexing characteristics.

Storing the string itself would make sense in few cases, eg if it's a hash string used in an API, or it's meant to be shown to humans. In this case, the data will always come as a string and will always have to be converted to a string to be used. In this case the constant conversions will probably cost more than the storage benefits.

Comment: It's fixed-length.  It is an API hash string, a known value from a video I uploaded and that's the key generated for that video.  In this context I'm logging that it was accessed, not doing anything else with it other than generating counts of what's being viewed.  Thank you.